# Conditional highlighting rules

Tags: conditional, number

I would like to highlight fields with amount 0 with red colour. And all the others to be without colour. 
For some reason I'm getting all the fields red when I set conditional highlighting as on the screenshot.

Do you know what I'm doing wrong please?

thank you

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide RANGE for record count.

For Example :

[image: Conditional Highlighting]

I've set parameters to conditionally highlight items as RED if they have greater than 0 counts and white if they have less than OR EQUAL to 1 count.
The first color code is for PICKLIST VALUE, second for GREATER THAN, and third for LESS THAN.
Hope it helps you. :)